# Status of a functional Male with hidden functional Female internal organs

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, kohen-priest, science, mamzer

I've found out this condition where a Male has a certain genetic condition where the primitive female organs, present in every foetus, are not absorbed and develop as "usual".
[A documented case in the UK](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2943702/Businessman-hysterectomy-discovering-WOMB-normal-male-organs.html)

This male, genetically and externally male, will also have internal female organs. Sometimes these organs aren't only there but are also functional, meaning the **male** has monthly menstruations which come out in his urine etc.

**I emphasise** this individual **is a male** who can *father* children with a **woman**.

His status, as far as my research went, is of a regular man, since *no female genitalia is apparent* and he can in fact have kids with a woman.
[Link to halacha summary](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/cohen-1.htm)

**The Question Is:** What if he impregnates himself since the sperm can go up and reach his own **eggs**? What would be the status of such child? This process **is** possible and could happen inadvertently, without his will or even knowledge until things "complicate"

**Bonus Question:** What if he is a **Cohen**?

Comment: I'm not actually sure about my close vote, but I thought I would put it in the queue for others to see, or for this question to be change to explicitly draw distinctions. For example, the method of impregnation is kind of unclear in this question, whereas the other question was kind of obvious.

Comment: the method of impregnation is the semen going up the channel and reaching the eggs etc. Basically, it's all "internally" connected and during an ejaculation, some of the semen can go the other way and this man would impregnate himself. My question is about who would this child be, not a mamzer (from the other question) but what would s/he be? Ben & Bat Yehuda Somesurname??

Comment: also, the "son" could be born with the same issue due to how this problem is passed on etc...

Comment: It wouldn't be "Ben and Bat Yehuda" because that'd mean "son and daughter of Yehuda" whereas the child will unlikely be androgynous. I assume you mean to ask whether the same parent would be referred to when we use "ben [father]" and also when we use "ben [mother]"? If so, please edit that into this question. (Also please edit in what your question is if he is a Cohen. This site is meant for precise questions, not open-ended discussion.) Then if the question isn't about mamzer status it can certainly be reopened.